# R - subset categories

Tags: r, subset

I have a large dataframe with these columns: "id" and "role". The id columns is not unique and role is either X or Y.

Reproducible example:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  'id' = sample(1:30, 100, replace=T),
  'role' = sample(c("X", "Y"), 100, replace =T)
)
```

Here is example of the data:

```
>head(Data):
      id role
    1 28    X
    2 11    Y
    3  1    Y
    4 30    X
    5 27    Y
    6  3    Y
```

I know I can get a subset like this:

```
subset(Data, Role == 'X')
```

As ID is repeated - sometimes with different roles - I would like to be able to do a subset of those who are only X, and those who are only Y, and those who have both roles for in a pseudocode like below:

```
Only_X_Role = subset(...)
Only_Y_Role = subset(...)
Both_X_and_Y_Roles = subset(...)
```

- how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, cross-tabulate `id`s and `role`s:

```
xtab <- with(Data,table(id,role))
```

Then, `subset` by `id` - separately for `id`s that have no "X" role:

```
Only_X_Role <- subset(Data,id %in% rownames(xtab)[xtab[,"X"]==0])
```

Then for `id`s that have no "Y" role:

```
Only_Y_Role <- subset(Data,id %in% rownames(xtab)[xtab[,"Y"]==0])
```

Finally, for `id`s that have both roles - or whose row in `xtab` has no zeros:

```
Both_X_and_Y_Roles <- subset(Data,id %in% rownames(xtab)[rowSums(xtab==0)==0])
```

Comment: Only issue is that the results from this and the other answer are different and this is a bit troubling.

Comment: Getting different results is indeed troubling. Can you find a minimal example where the two approaches differ and edit it into your question?

Comment: thanks - I figured it out - the issue was that the subset does not care about other columns so for example if the record is replicated with other values for other columns, the first instance is subsetted, and thus it's hard to group by other columns later. Thus when I group by other columns first, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like (this way you don't need to specify the actual `role` values, thus theoretically you could have many more different values in `role` and this code will still work properly)

```
library(reshape2)
Data2 <- dcast(Data, id ~ role)
Data2 <- data.frame(id = Data2[, 1], apply(Data2[, -1], 2, function(x) as.numeric(x > 0)))
list2env(split(Data2, Data2[, -1]), .GlobalEnv)
```

This will create 3 data sets called:

```
`1.0`, `0.1`, `1.1`
```

For example

```
`1.0`
##    id X Y
## 13 13 1 0
## 16 16 1 0
## 17 17 1 0
## 21 21 1 0
```

Comment: Yeah I am trying to accept and vote, it highlights then it disappears.

Comment: Ok, never mind. Im glad it worked for you. Btw, if you save `temp <- split(Data2, Data2[, -1])` in some object you can set the names that makes more sense to you using `names(temp) <-` and then run `list2env(temp, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @Kash, What's the issue with this answer?

Comment: so this worked well with the smaller dataframe, but with one that many columns such as region and group, one of the groups produces incorrect results for the role. I might be wrong but think the cause of it is that in the larger DF, dcast assigns a (seemingly random) column for value.var - and I don't know how to troubleshoot it.